# When I post a swf player in a wall with my application, it opens in a new window

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, flash

I'm suffering problems with my facebook application.

I want to post a swf player and it works, but when the user click in the image, the swf player doesn't appear in the wall, it opens in a new window.

How can I fix it?

```
$result = $facebook->api('/' . $user_id . '/feed' , 'post' , array(
"name" => "appname",
"message" => "test",
"picture" => "http://www.domain.com/image.png", 
"link" => "http://www.domain.com",
"caption" => "test",
"description" => "test",
"source" => 'http://www.domain.com/playlist.swf?file='.$selected_value.''
));
```

Thank you very much

Comment: I have the same issue. It seems facebook no longer allows to play swf directly from the news feed. Looking for the solution, if there is any...

Answer (score 2):

Attaching SWFs for inline play within the feed is certainly still possible. However, if you specify a http SWF, then we will only enable embedding for users that are browsing with secure mode disabled - otherwise mixed content warnings would be generated by the browser.

If you want your embed to work for all users, then you should host the SWF on a https server.